how to find closed form for $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} \ln x}{x^2+1} dx $?
I tried to find closed form for
$$ \Omega=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} \ln x}{x^2+1} dx $$
by Laplace transform I got
$$ =\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left( \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1} \frac{1}{s+x} dx \right)(1)$$
then by evaluating the integral we get
$$ =\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left( -\frac{1}{s^2+1} \left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}+\frac{\ln^2 s}{2} \right) \right)(1)$$
So
$$ =-\frac{\pi^2}{8} \sin 1-\frac{1}{2} \mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln^2 s}{s}\frac{s}{s^2+1} \right)(1)$$
then by The Convolution Theorem I got
$$ =-\frac{\pi^2}{8} \sin 1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left((\ln x+\gamma \right)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{6})\cos(1-x)dx$$
finally I find
$$ =-\frac{\cos 1}{2} I_1-\frac{\sin 1}{2}I_2+\gamma \cos 1 \text{Si}(1)-\gamma \sin 1 \text{Ci}(1)+\frac{\sin 1}{2} \left(\gamma^2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)$$
where
$$I_1=\int_0^1 \ln^2x \cos xdx=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!(2k+1)^3}$$
and
$$I_2=\int_0^1 \ln^2x \sin xdx=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!(k+1)^3}$$
both can be expressed by hypergeometric 2F3 function but is it possible to find more simple closed form ?

Your solution has 6 ingredients and I only have one. I doubt there's a simple closed form. $-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } G_{2,4}^{3,2}\left(\frac{1}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \
\end{array}
\right)$

@MariuszIwaniuk a closed form is the expression with the simplest operations, no matter how many there are. and using majer G function is not closed form
